# Transform problem with creating a tab bar animation in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, tabbar

I've got this project going on built with ReactJS and its got this interesting nav bar [image: like this thing]

I want to have this background grey container somehow transform its position and go to the icon that was clicked, and it has to do it with animation with the feel of sliding down and up.

I got stuck as I don't actually know how to do this... can anyone help me with this? 
Thanks...
P.S.
I have a codepen link which I want to share for the purpose of demonstration but stackoverflow won't let me post a link and gives me error of indenting code or something I don't precisely understand... so if you take time to search tab bar animation on codepen it might help to visualize what I mean.

Comment: We cannot write the code for you. We can help debug errors in your code, but you don't seem to have any, which means we can't help you.

Comment: I was looking for help in terms of the concept of doing it , not the code writing. thanks either way.